# Power BI with date/time format

Tags: business-intelligence, powerbi

I am very to the Power BI and I am learning it by myself. I have just sign up free power BI account. For learning purpose I took data of "[Case Data
 from San Francisco](https://data.sfgov.org/City-Infrastructure/Case-Data-from-San-Francisco-311-SF311-/vw6y-z8j6?)" I exported those data in xlxs format and imported into the Power BI.

As per the suggestion of Power BI, I just defined the Excel data to table by pressing
**ctrl + T.**

Now the problem  like

1. I cannot make any chart by status (i.e. open or close)
2. I cannot make any chart by date on the basis of close date or open date

Many more things. Now my question is do I am missing something? Do I have do something with excel file before importing it?

Sorry I am asking lot of questions. I am just new learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of resources for getting you starte. Here's a good starting point: 
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-getting-started/